# How to fix problem with multiple menu item from material ui

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

When I try to put Menu component many times I get wrong popup list.
I show my problem on codesandbox link below. I put data-id attributes to show in chromedev is popu list is correct.

https://wt7jy.csb.app/

```
     <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} data-id="1">
          Profile
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>

      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu2"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu2"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} data-id="2">
          Profile
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
```

I expect to show correct popup list. When I click left data-id should be "1" and on righ shoud by "2"
Actually when I click on list 1 I get "2"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem with the `anchorEl` in second `Menu`. It should be

```
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu2"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick} // Here you have to set target to `anchorEl2`
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
       <Menu
        id="simple-menu2"
        anchorEl={anchorEl2}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl2)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose} data-id="2">
          Profile
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
```

Here is the working demo for you.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-material-menu-jnnxnc

Comment: every menu element should have your own state? Is the way to get same in more dynamic way?

Comment: Yes we can set it to dynamic. It's depends on requirement.

Comment: ok i found problem. I used global state instead loclal state in component. Your solution bring me to right way. Thanks

Comment: Yes, You can simply use one state for all type of menu and pass the name onClick of button to change the selected state only.